# regular expression: how to find text up to a specific character?

Tags: regex

I try to isolate the list of Delphi units used in... a Delphi unit. For this I use the pattern

```
(uses|Uses|USES)(.*\r\n)(.+\r\n)+
```

It works quite well in this case:

```
uses
  SysUtils, Classes, CTLibEnhQuery, CTLibQuery, CTLibDatabase, DB,
  CTMemDataSet, CTDataSet,CTStoredProc, DosCommand, ActnList, CTQuery,
  FlyingOp, Tools, FindFile, Dialogs;
```

but in this one

```
uses Variants, HyperStr, Config;
{$R *.dfm}
```

I also get the {$R *.dfm}. So my question is: how to get the text until the semicolon but not after? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, instead of `(uses|Uses|USES)`, switch your regex matcher into case-insensitive mode. Then do:

```
uses(([^;]|[\n\r])*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

`Group 1` will hold the list you're after.